# Regex makes Ruby freeze entirely

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, freeze

So I just stumbled upon this issue, when I try to match specific data with some regex in Ruby (this applies to Rails server and Rails console and even simple IRB), it just freezes entirely for couple of minutes, no reaction whatsoever.

So this is regex:

```
^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$
```

And this is data I am trying to match with this regex.

```
http://sub.domain.com/folder_1/?getparam=true
```

For example, using match method, like this:

```
"http://sub.domain.com/folder_1/?getparam=true".match(/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/)
```

Eventually, after around 2 minutes, it returns result, but I mean 2 minutes, for regex, it does not seem to be that hard for me.

If I remove ?getparam=true from the string, it matches perfectly.

This issue is reproduced in Rails console, IRB console and Rails server.

I am running

```
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
Rails 3.2.8
```

Is it really about regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [it is about the regex](http://rubular.com/r/u1A4CKmdBU):

[image: Imgur]

Try this regex:

```
^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)\/?$
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Think you can explain why will it take forever to parse for Ruby? For example Python handles it perfectly well.

Comment: I'm not sure, I think that it has to do with `/([\/\w \.-]*)*$/` (the asterisk inside and outside of the capture braces), it might have to do with the regex implementation (pcre vs. python)

Comment: @Screatch Have a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html, it explains what’s happening (and why it works when you remove `?getparam=true` (which is equivalent to the `y` in the example on the page).

Comment: @UriAgassi Ruby has it’s own Ruby implementation: https://github.com/k-takata/Onigmo (although it’s merged into the Ruby source).